# Best way to generate ticket number that resets daily

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ticket-system

So I am making a ticket management system where a customer will come and he/she will be assigned a ticket number.
I want to keep it simple and wants to generate a 4 or 5 digit ticket number something like:

00001
00002
00003

This will reset daily i.e. a customer may be assigned ticket 00005 today and tomorrow another customer can be assigned that number (because tickets will expire each day)
One way of doing is to keep count in some table from where I read what was last number and just add one in it to generate next number. But this can cause some concurrency issues if two or more people come at the same time!?
So I was thinking if I can use SQL Server identity column for this purpose because it will take care of generating sequential number. Problem is it won't reset next day and it will keep on adding so eventually it will become a very big number.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Ok I found out I can create a composite primary key combining ID and DATE columns and then reset ID to 0 every night.

Comment: How about [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ? To reset: [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Fildor This looks interesting but a little complex for my need. But I will definitely look into it.

Comment: It's basically an auto-incrementing number generator. May look complex at first but in practice it's actually less complex than any approach I read in the question.

Comment: Using a sequencer with a job that resets it to 1 at midnight could work. Except for the records around mignight, the first record past midnight might have the wrong id.

Comment: Here's another way to do it: make an auto identity. To get your 'daily' number, subtract the first record of the day from it.

Comment: Why do you need the number to reset every day? If you think about it, that will be very confusing for end-users, I think.

Comment: If you just need a 5 digit number and don't have more than 99.999 numbers a day, just take the last 5 digits.

Comment: @Fildor Post your comment as answer as it is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate SQL Server Feature that comes to my mind is a [Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

It can be reset with [ALTER SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with a single integer column, and in your ticket creation stored procedure wrap the incrementing of that column in a transaction. Reset the integer value to 0 when you want to reset the count. Like below:

```
-- table to hole the next ticket number

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ticketNumber](
        [nextTicket] [int] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ticketNumber] VALUES (0)
```

Then a stored proc to use the table wrapped in a transaction:

```
begin tran

declare @nextTicket int
update ticketNumber set @nextTicket=nextTicket=nextTicket+1
--do you other sql here

commit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 columns in the database table, `DataTime` and `UnixTime`, then the `unixtime` is incremental.

Then create a stored procedure to set number of ticket for every day for all records for day.

After per request to get ticket number you can generate all ticket numbers